# Asana Webhooks: is there no task delete event implemented in Asana API?

Tags: webhooks, asana, asana-api

I implemented [Asana Webhooks](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/webhooks#create) to my project and everything works great, I only don't receive **delete events**. When I **delete** a task or **permanently delete** a task there is no request to my endpoint. Are there no delete events implemented or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that deletion events do occur. Here's an example output we receive on deletion:

`{
   user: {
      id: 107710117683398,
      name: "Muhan"
   },
   created_at: "2017-03-29T08:45:05.409Z",
   type: "task",
   action: "deleted",
   resource: {
      id: 304894652565829,
      name: "Dashboard Task Creation Test 7"
   },
   parent: null
}`

Comment: @MuhanAlim did you have to delete it permanetly?

Comment: Nope, worked on normal deletion. Try posting the snippet of your code where you're looking out for the events and we can try and debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

There should be deleted events for tasks. It can be tricky because by the time the event gets sent, you have "lost access" to the task so only the ID gets sent.

Comment: No, nothing is sent. I don't get any request from asana on task delete event.

Comment: Deletion events are one of the supported types in Asana webhooks.  I will confirm that there isn't a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the webhook to your project, not the task itself. The project webhook will report task deletions.

Comment: Thank you I will try this. But what about if your task is not connected to any of your projects?

Comment: @Silko Actually I'm not sure. And now I'm having my webhooks delete themselves as soon as a task is modified in any way. Very strange. I'm in touch with API support to figure out what's up. Not a big fan of the Asana API so far, though.

Comment: do you still have problems with webhooks delete themselves? I am also having some strange problems with this webhooks now.